# Removing a directory from a particular git branch

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

I've a peculiar situation in my hand. Say I've a git repo named git_test. It has 3 branches:

1. master
2. branch1
3. branch2

And it has 2 folders(dir1, dir2) and README file.

Now, master branch has README file alone.
branch1 has dir1.
But when I created branch2 and checked out, it had both dir1 and dir2. (I had pushed the branch to remote repo by this time)

Now my question has two parts.

1. How do I remove dir1 from branch2? (That is, I want branchN to have only dirN, not the other directories in the repo)
2. Is there a way to avoid this in the future, at the time of branch creation itself? (Selecting which director(y/ies) I want to include in that particular branch?

TIA

Comment: As far as I know git doesn't track directories just files? Maybe the directory will go away if you delete it's content.

Comment: But I don't want that directory to go away from the repo. I want that directory away from the current branch alone. Like maintain different directories in different branches

Comment: May be you are doing something fundamentally wrong. Why do you need to maintain different directories in different branches. what are the contents of that directory?

Comment: @robert I'm not sure if it's fundamentally wrong. I've to maintain the main application as well as the practiced code in my repo, under separate branches. I don't want the main application code in the practice code's branch and the same goes for the main application code branch. In essence, I want to push them under separate branches, so that it becomes easier for the reviewer to review and merge them accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that both branches share history with `master`, and that your
mistake here was that you did `git checkout -b branch2` while still on
`branch1`.  If that's not true, then you need to go about fixing this up a
different way.

So given that both `branch1` and `branch2` share history with `master`, you can
fix `branch2` by doing:

```
$ git checkout branch2
$ git rebase --onto master branch1 branch2
```

This will take the commits introduced on `branch2` and rebase them so that they
derive from `master`.  In other words, this `git rebase` will drop the commits
introduced in `branch1`--but not in `master`--and leave only the commits
introduced in `branch2`.

For the second part of your question, no, there's no way to tell Git to keep
certain directories and not others.  Git deals with commits and snapshots of
trees, and `git branch` is simply saying "start a new branch based off of this
commit".  If the history is meant to be completely disconnected, then you can
create an *orphan* branch--a branch that will have a commit with no parent
commit:

```
$ git checkout --orphan NAME
```

This will create a new branch, pre-populated with the current tree.  You can
then choose to remove directories you don't want with `git rm -rf <path>`.  Or
completely remove everything with `git rm -rf .`.

There are some consequences of doing this though.  Merging branches that are
disconnected from each other can result in many conflicts because Git will not
know how some of the data got there, and how to smartly merge the data.  If, on
the other hand, you never intend to merge them (such as the `gh-pages` branches
on GitHub), then they're quite fine to keep around.

I'll make a couple more suggestions here though.  The first is that if these
really are supposed to be separate branches with completely separate histories,
then you probably want them in separate repositories.

Also, if you're on a branch--say `branch10`--and want to create a new branch
based on `master`, you can do that easily with:

```
$ git checkout -b NAME master
```

In other words, you can choose which commit or branch to use as your starting
point.

Finally, since it isn't clear why you want to maintain directories in different
branches, I'd suggest you take a step back and examine what you're trying to
accomplish.  There's a lot that's possible in Git, but choosing a methodology
that goes against its strengths can make the tool much more difficult to use and
the repository harder to share.

Comment: As for the question of what am trying to accomplish it's rather simple. I'm just trying to get an understanding of what's possible and what's not and if there's an easier way of doing it, rather than adding the directories selectively in git add. And yes, the purpose here is to differentiate between practice code on a branch and the main application code, all under the same repo.

Comment: @glnarayanan That's great!  Definitely experiment.  In a development workflow, you'll want to create topic branches either from `master` or from some other integration branch (some people use one called `develop`).  The `git co -b BRANCH_NAME STARTING_POINT` form is great because you can start the branch off from the correct location even though you're currently on a different branch.

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks for helping me out here :)

Comment: @glnarayanan You're very welcome.  I wish you the best of luck learning Git!

Answer (score 0):

At a guess (I'm not sure you've given us enough information), if `branch2` is based on `branch1` then it will contain whatever `branch1` does. In other words, you may have this situation:

```
master-->branch1-->branch2
```

If that's the case, then you can achieve what you want by basing `branch2` on `master` instead, i.e.

```
        -->branch1
master-|
        -->branch2
```

In the situation outlined above, you can change the one to the other by checking out `branch2` and then executing:

```
git rebase --onto master branch1
```

This cuts off the bit of `branch2` from `branch1` onwards (exclusive) and pastes it on top of `master`.

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this particularly, but it will work. If you later change the common stuff in `master` (like the `README`), then you can simply rebase all of your branches on `master` to incorporate the changes into them.

Comment: Will try this out now !